# How do you calculate indexed price changes interactively based on the date being moused over on the x-axis in Altair?

Tags: javascript, python, altair, vega-lite

I am trying to create [**an Altair version**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_1ReOeaMoYxQPONhaXoGfZcR47CEQD0M?usp=sharing) of this [Vega-Lite API Interactive Index Chart](https://observablehq.com/@vega/vega-lite-interactive-index-chart), which itself was adapted from this [Vega-Lite JSON version](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_index_chart.html).

In Altair, I cannot get the transform_lookup and transform_calculate to work with the mouseover selection, such that the indexed price values displayed on the y-axis for each of the symbols are calculated based on the date being moused over on the x-axis.

In **Vega-Lite**, the following transforms, i.e. lookup and calculate, calculate indexed price changes based on the date being moused over on the x-axis:

```
chart = {
  const mouseover = vl
    .selectSingle("index")
    .on("mouseover")
    .encodings("x")
    .nearest(true)
    .init({ x: { year: 2005, month: 1, date: 1 } });

  const base = vl.mark().encode(
    vl.x().fieldT("date").axis(null)
  );

   const hiddenPoints = base
    .markPoint({ opacity: 0.1 })
    .select(mouseover)
    .encode(
      // Let's color code it interactively to demonstrate it is working, but we will remove it later
      vl.color().if(mouseover, vl.value("firebrick")).value("steelblue")
    );
  
  const line = base
    .markLine()
    .transform(
      vl.lookup("symbol").from(mouseover.key("symbol")),
      vl.calculate(
        "datum.index && datum.index.price > 0 ? (datum.price - datum.index.price)/datum.index.price : 0"
      ).as("indexed_price")
    )
    .encode(
      vl.y().fieldQ("indexed_price").axis({ format: "%" }),
      vl.color().fieldN("symbol")
    );

  const tooltipBase = base
    .transform(vl.filter(mouseover))
    .encode(vl.color().value("firebrick"));

  const tooltip = vl.layer(
    tooltipBase.markRule({ strokeWidth: 0.5 }),
    tooltipBase.markText({ align: "center", fontWeight: 100 }).encode(
      vl.y().value(310),
      vl.text().fieldT("date").timeUnit("yearmonth")
    )
  );

  return vl
    .layer(hiddenPoints, line, tooltip)
    .data("data/stocks.csv")
    .width(width - 150)
    .height(300)
    .render();
}
```

[Vega-Lite API Interactive Index Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUyvA.png)

When I attempt to translate this code into **Altair**, I cannot get the mouseover event to lookup the date and symbols and compute the indexed price change values for each of the symbols correctly.  The hiddenPoints appear, but the indexed price change lines for each of the symbols do not appear:

```
mouseover = alt.selection_single(name='index', 
                                 on='mouseover', 
                                 encodings=['x'], 
                                 nearest=True, 
                                 init={ 'x': { 'year': 2005, 'month': 1, 'date': 1 } })

base = alt.Chart(stocks).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T', axis=None, title=None),
)

hiddenPoints = base.mark_point(opacity=0.1).add_selection(mouseover).encode(
    color=alt.condition(mouseover, alt.value('firebrick'), alt.value('steelblue'))
)

line = base.mark_line().transform_lookup(
    lookup='symbol', 
    from_=alt.LookupData(data='index', key='symbol', fields=['date', 'price'])
).transform_calculate(
    indexed_price="datum.index && datum.index.price > 0 ? (datum.price - datum.index.price) / datum.index.price : 0"
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('indexed_price:Q', title='Indexed Price', axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    color=alt.Color('symbol:N', title='Symbol')
)

tooltipBase = base.transform_filter(mouseover).encode(
    color=alt.value('firebrick')
)

tooltip = alt.layer(
    tooltipBase.mark_rule(strokeWidth=0.5),
    tooltipBase.mark_text(align='center', fontWeight=100).encode(
      y=alt.value(310),
      text='yearmonth(date):T'
    )
)

alt.layer(hiddenPoints, line, tooltip).properties(
    width=650,
    height=300
)
```

[Altair Interactive Index Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0TRp.png)

In **Altair**, how do I use the mouseover event with transform_lookup and transform_calculate to lookup the date and symbols and compute the indexed price change values for each of the symbols?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Have you seen this example in the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_tooltip.html)? It is not exactly the same but seems similar to the functionality you want.

Comment: @joelostblom Thank you for your reply.  Yes, I've seen this example.  It's very helpful for creating the transparent / hidden layer of selectors, as well as the vertical rule line that interactively shows the position on the x-axis.  I haven't been able to figure out how to modify it to use the position on the x-axis as the comparison point, such that as the user moves across the chart the lines for the categories are re-computed as percent differences from the y-value at the x-axis reference point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's roughly the equivalent in Altair:

```python
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

data = data.stocks.url

index = alt.selection_single(
  name='index', on='mouseover', nearest=True, encodings=['x'],
  init={"x": {"year": 2005, "month": 1, "date": 1}})

transparent_points = alt.Chart(data).mark_point(opacity=0).encode(
  x='date:T'
).add_selection(index)

lines = alt.Chart(data).transform_lookup(
  'symbol', from_=alt.LookupSelection('symbol', 'index')
).transform_calculate(
  indexed_price="datum.index && datum.index.price > 0 ? "
                "(datum.price - datum.index.price)/datum.index.price : 0"
).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='indexed_price:Q',
    color='symbol:N'
)

rules = alt.Chart(data).transform_filter(
  index
).mark_rule().encode(
  x='date:T'
)

alt.layer(transparent_points, lines, rules).properties(width=600)
```